# Center the text in content

Tags: html, css

How can I center the main content in the middle of the page - http://www.hentaireader.com/ ??

It looks like it is shifted a bit to the left for some reason ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#centerContent` either needs to be the same width as the container div so that text will fill up that space, `950px`, or it needs to have a `margin: 0px auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float and add a margin (left/right) auto:

```
#centerContent {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 780px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#center{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
height:400px;
width:800px;
margin-left:-400px;
margin-top:-200px;
}
```

margin-left and top should be negative half of your height and width.  Perfectly centered.